# On a localized ring tensor with a module

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $S$ be a multiplicative subset
of $A$ and $M$ be an $A$-module. The questions says to
"describe a natural isomorphism $(S^{-1}A) \otimes_A M \cong S^{-1}M $
as $A$-modules". I manage to show these two are isomorphic using the universal property but what do they mean by a natural isomorphism and what is this isomorphism?
Thanks!

Comment: "I manage to show these two are isomorphic using the universal property but [...] what is this isomorphism? " ... Well, the one which comes out of your proof!

Comment: Oh! That was silly of me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the map $(a/s)\otimes m\mapsto (am)/s$